# How do I generate random numbers in an array that add up to a defined total?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, random

I need to randomly generate an array with 7 slots in Java. All these slots must have a value of at LEAST 1, but combined, have a total value of another defined number.  They also all need to be an int value, no 1.5 or 0.9816465684646 numbers.
Example:

```
int a=10;

int[] ar = new int[7]
ar[0] = 1
ar[1] = 1
ar[2] = 2
ar[3] = 2
ar[4] = 1
ar[5] = 2
ar[6] = 1
```

I want it to generate something like that, but if int a=15, all the numbers would total 15 in any order

Comment: This might even be worth an `algorithm` tag.

Comment: OP, do you know about random variables and probability distributions?  This question can't be answered until you define more precisely what you mean by random.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The standard way to generate N random numbers that add to a given sum is to think of your sum as a number line, generate N-1 random points on the line, sort them, then use the differences between the points as your final values.  To get the minimum 1, start by subtracting N from your sum, run the algorithm given, then add 1 back to each segment.

```
public class Rand {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 8;
        int sum = 100;
        java.util.Random g = new java.util.Random();

        int vals[] = new int[count];
        sum -= count;

        for (int i = 0; i < count-1; ++i) {
            vals[i] = g.nextInt(sum);
        }
        vals[count-1] = sum;

        java.util.Arrays.sort(vals);
        for (int i = count-1; i > 0; --i) {
            vals[i] -= vals[i-1];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) { ++vals[i]; }

        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            System.out.printf("%4d", vals[i]);
        }
        System.out.printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's very interesting

Comment: Could you show a little code so I can see what would be going on?

Comment: Yeah, I should probably show some code. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: This is a good approach, but the problem is a little harder when the numbers are constrained to be integers. The devil will be in the details.

Comment: @TedHopp I'm not sure why the integerness makes a problem. The average difference between the numbers is still going to be N/sum

Comment: @Cruncher - Yeah. I was thinking that ties would be a problem (avoiding them while maintaining uniformity takes a little care). But on second thought, I think that ties aren't a problem at all. I take it back.

Comment: Thank you so much! this is exactly what I was looking for!  I changed a few things to blend with my cose but this was perfect.  Thank you! :)

Comment: Ok, I found one issue, I replaced your "int sum = 100;" with "int sum = num + 7;"  by default, num it set to 1, which should make 1 of my 7 numbers randomly a 2. (as num increases, so does the numbers).  As it stands, while num = 1, only the 7th number is a 2.  Is there any way with num = 1 that the index with a 2 in it jumps around?

Comment: Ah, that's right--this method won't work well for integers if count and sum are too close. You will have to randomly shuffle the results afterward (which won't hurt in the general case anyway).

Comment: Can you explain how to shuffle? The order of the numbers does not matter really, I would just like inconsistency

Comment: Standard shuffle algorithm is called "Fisher-Yates". Java implements it in Collections.shuffle(), but that would require changing the code above to use an ArrayList rather than a primitive array.

Comment: Why sort? Also, what is the joint probability distribution for the resulting collection of numbers?

Comment: You have to sort the points so that the intervals you get are between neighbors.

Comment: This is very interesting, do you mind to explain what happen on `vals[i] -= vals[i-1];` and `++vals[i];`?

Answer (score 14):

A good way to achieve uniformity is, for example, to fill up `a = 15` units into an 8 element array:

1. Put 1 in each element in the array as this is your requirement, you have now 7 values left to distribute
2. Roll a random number between 0 and the max index of the array, and add 1 to that element, and subtract 1 from 7. Do this until 7 goes down to zero.

In this way, you'll meet your minimum conditions by having each element have minimum value 1. Then you distribute the remaining totals in a completely random way.

Comment: +1, don't see any better possible solution. I was pondering on how to get uniformity. My plight here is that they may be too uniform. For a sufficiantly large a, all numbers are going to be very close together, to the point where it's hard to tell there was any randomness.

Comment: So what would I change from what you said to make it a 7 element array?  I only need 7 numbers

Comment: The max any of these numbers would be is 99, no numbers greater then that

Comment: @user2462068 Everything applies, I just chose 8 as a random number to help explain my point. Let's say you have 7 array spots, and you want to fell them with 15 numbers. So first, you put "1" into all 7 spots, reducing your total available numbers to 8. Then you randomly distribute the remaining 8 numbers throughout the indices by generating a random number between 0 and the max index, and then adding 1 to that array element (don't forget to subtract 1 from total remaining numbers)

Comment: Thank you! I just have one other question that has to do with this, but not quite.  I am making all this section of code within a method so that I can call it when I need to.  My main method is refusing to call it as it's "non-static".  I tried making my generating method static, but then I could not use the generator lines of the code.  Any help how I can call my generator method from my main?

Comment: You're not really placing _random_ numbers into the array, though. As @Cruncher pointed out, probability will dictate that the elements of the array will likely be very uniform, distributed over a small range. But, perhaps the OP is ok with that.

Comment: @GriffeyDog I've spent the last 15 minutes, trying to think of a way to enumerate all possible permutations of numbers in the array and randomly pick one of those

Comment: @user2462068 When you made your method static, what was the problem when calling it? I'm assuming you're calling this method directly from `main`, which is why it must be static. Also, @GriffeyDog and @Cruncher are right in that it will produce UNIFORM numbers

Comment: This will perform terribly when your sum is very large.

Comment: The error I am getting is "non-static method monGen() cannot be refrenced from a static context"  Where monGen is my generating method.  And yes, it is being called directly from main.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker The OP said his values will not exceed 99.

Comment: @user2462068 Add the word "static" before the return type of your monGen() method. ie, `public static void monGen()` where `void` can be whatever return type you're using.

Comment: "public static int[] monGen()", but then an error jumps to this line "int rGen = r.nextInt(6)+1;" saying "int rGen = r.nextInt(6)+1; =>Cannot access instance variable "r" from static context.<"

Comment: This is going to be slow when `a` is large.  A far more efficient solution would be the one described by Lee Daniel Crocker.

Comment: @user2462068 You're going to need to read up on the difference between static and instance variables and methods in Java. Here's a great place to start: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: @DavidWallace As I pointed out above, the OP specified numbers will be 99 or less.

Answer (score 2):

Adding on to what @Kon said, you could use two random numbers rather than one for more randomness. That is:

```
Fill every element in the array with the value 1
valuesToDistribute = a - array.length-1
randomIndex = Roll a number between 0 and array.length-1
randomValue = Roll a number between 1 and valuesToDistribute
Add to randomIndex the value randomValue
Subtract randomValue from valuesToDistribute
Repeat until valuesToDistribute = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

My java is horrible, so I'm not providing the actual code here, as it would probably be wrong.  I've done this exact thing in SQL before though, so I know it works...

1. Let Y be the Total value you want the elements to add up to
2. Begin a loop with variable Z going from 1 to X where X is the number elements in your array (here called AR)
3. In the loop, set AR(Z) to a random number between 1 and Y-X+Z
4. Subtract the new value from Y, so Y = Y - AR(Z)
5. End loop : back to step 2, advancing Z by 1