# Generate an array that adds up to specific value using only 2 numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I need randomly generate a "grid" where the total of the integers in the array add up to **8 (or any #)** with only using 1 and 2.

Example output would be:

```
[1, 2, 2, 1, 2]
```

or

```
[1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

or

```
[2, 2, 2, 2]
```

This is basically [How do I generate random numbers in an array that add up to a defined total?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600348/how-do-i-generate-random-numbers-in-an-array-that-add-up-to-a-defined-total) but for JS.

Comment: Any distribution of values required?

Comment: Generate random 1/2 until the sum of all values is >=6. Then add a 2 if sum=6 or a 1 if sum=7. That´s it, one solution finished. For another one, start again with random numbers

Comment: Since most of the answers in the question you found are in pseudocode anyway, can't you simply write them down in JavaScript? Have you tried at all? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: What have you tried?  While the sum of the numbers is less than the max number: create a random number between 1 and 2; check if the sum plus this number is still less than or equal to the maximum; if it is, add it to the list, otherwise, add 1 to the list.  Increment the sum by the number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
for (var res=[], sum=0; sum<8; sum+=res[res.length-1])
    res.push(Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * Math.min(8-sum, 2)));
```

Comment: Concise - yes; clean - rather not :-)

Answer (score 1):

Based on my comment above, here is how it might work in JavaScript (see [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/kujofezo/1/edit?js,console))

```
var max = 8;
var sum = 0;
var numbers = [];

while (sum < max) {
  var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);
  if (sum + number > max) {
    numbers.push(1);
    sum += 1;
  } else {
    numbers.push(number);
    sum += number;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion to achieve this ,

```
WaysToGet(8) = WaysToGet(7) + 1 and WaysToGet(6) + 2
```

so try something like this,

```
int WaysToGet(int x) {
     if(x == 1 || x == 2)  {
      return x; 
     }
     print(WaysToGet(x-1) + "," + 1);
     print(WaysToGet(x-2) + "," + 2);
    }
```

I have not tested it but it's an idea you can follow to implement this.

Comment: OP seems to want *one* *random* array, not all of them. Also, why do you concatenate strings to the result when your function does not return anything?

Comment: Btw, the question is about javascript.

Comment: @Bergi Fixed the code , I was just trying to suggest a method so OP can implement using it , but your answer is much more correct in context of javascript

Comment: Hm, that still doesn't seem to work. In case `x` is not `1` or `2`, the function doesn't return an int. Try `return` instead of `print`, and choose one of the two recursive calls by random (`WayToGet(8)` = `WayToGet(7) + 1` **or** `WayToGet(6) + 2`)