# Generate number with rule

Tags: c#, random, numbers

I have a collection number like this

```
var maxLength=250;
var range=new int[]{48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75};
```

And I want get 4 random numbers from those collection and if I sum it the result should be same with 'maxLength'. How I could do that?
I am already read from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600348/how-do-i-generate-random-numbers-in-an-array-that-add-up-to-a-defined-total#_=_) but it from 1 to 100 and my number collection is excluding some of those number
I already try doing it like this

```
        var random = new Random();
        var vals = new int[count];
        maxLength -= count;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            vals[i] = range.Select(x => range[random.Next(0, range.Length)]).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        vals[count - 1] = maxLength;
        Array.Sort(vals);
        for (var i = count - 1; i > 0; --i)
        {
            vals[i] -= vals[i - 1];
        }
```

But the sum from vals still producing wrong value.

Comment: Side note - isn't this `Enumerable.Range(47, 76).Where(i => tes.Contains(i)).ToArray()` same as `tes`?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for duplicate. Already edit it :D

Comment: can you explain what is *result should be same with 'a'*? I don't see any `a` in your code. I believe you are talking about char code of 'a'. But still *result should be same with 'a'* is unclear

Comment: same with maxLength I mean. Sorry again

Answer (score 0):

So you would need to ensure that your inputs are even valid for this (e.g. there are 4 numbers that combined make maxLength), but for the input provided in the question this works:

```
  var maxLength = 250;
  var range = new int[] { 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75 };

  var rand = new Random();
  var resultingRandoms = new List<int>();
  while (true)
  {
    resultingRandoms = range.Select(y => range[rand.Next(0, range.Length)]).Take(4).ToList();
    if (resultingRandoms.Sum() == maxLength)
    {
      break;
    }
  }
```