# How to generate 6 random number where their sum is equal to a certain value?

Tags: python, numpy, random

I have looked at comparable questions such as:

1. [How to generate a list of random numbers so their sum would be equal to a randomly chosen number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31811267/how-to-generate-a-list-of-random-numbers-so-their-sum-would-be-equal-to-a-random)
2. [Generating a list of random numbers, summing to 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18659858/generating-a-list-of-random-numbers-summing-to-1)

but these do not seem to answer my question.

I would like to generate 6 random numbers where the sum of all numbers = 157750 (or well 5 random and the last to be the difference). I have looked at Dirichlet distribution and other methods but not really help.

Does anyone know how to approach this?

Comment: How about this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31814348/3129414 ?

Comment: It seems I still need to learn how to search better. Thanks for the speedy replies!