# Sampling of positive weights with sum unity and an equality constraint

Tags: r, random, dirichlet

Suppose I have a vector of positive weights `a=(a1, a2, a3, a4)` such that `a2=a3` and `a1+a2+a3+a4=1`. Is there any way to sample this kind of weights using R? I tried to think about using the Dirichlet distribution, but it gives no mechanism to force two of the variates to be equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sample evenly across the set `{(a1, a2, a3, a4 | a2=a3, a1+a2+a3+a4=1, a1>0, a2>0, a3>0, a4>0}`, I would first sample the value for `a2` (which is equal to `a3`). To do this we need to know the distribution of this value. If `a2 = a3 = r`, then we have `a1+a4 = 1-2r`; for positive a1 and a4 there is a line segment of length `(1-2k)*sqrt(2)` containing all feasible values of `a1` and `a4`. Integrating, the probability that `a2` is `k` or less is `4(k - k^2)`. In more detail:

```
Prob (a2 <= k) = Integral(0 to k) (1-2r)*sqrt(2) dr / Integral(0 to 0.5) (1-2r)*sqrt(2) dr
               = ((k-k^2)*sqrt(2)) / (sqrt(2)/4)
               = 4k - 4k^2
```

Thus, we can sample values for `a2` by selecting a uniformly distributed value `u~U(0, 1)` and setting `a2` to equal the value `k` for which `4k - 4k^2 = u`. Solving via the quadratic formula, this yields:

```
a2 = 0.5 * (1 - sqrt(1-u))
```

In R, we can sample 1000 values for `a2` with:

```
set.seed(144)
a2 <- 0.5 * (1 - sqrt(1 - runif(1000)))
a3 <- a2
```

Given a fixed value `a2 = a3 = k`, the value of `a1` is uniformly distributed in `[0, 1-2k]`:

```
a1 <- runif(1000) * (1 - 2*a2)
```

Having specified `a1`, `a2`, and `a3`, there is only one possible value for `a4`:

```
a4 <- 1 - a1 - a2 - a3
```

We can take a look at some of our sampled values:

```
head(cbind(a1, a2, a2, a4))
#              a1         a2         a2         a4
# [1,] 0.83455239 0.01251016 0.01251016 0.14042729
# [2,] 0.02744599 0.22932773 0.22932773 0.51389856
# [3,] 0.45835472 0.23860119 0.23860119 0.06444291
# [4,] 0.36843649 0.14679703 0.14679703 0.33796946
# [5,] 0.35109881 0.08702039 0.08702039 0.47486041
# [6,] 0.02916818 0.19942616 0.19942616 0.57197949
```

Here is the distribution of `a1` values (note that by symmetry this is identical to the distribution of the `a4` values). Because we select `a1` uniformly in the range `[0, 1-2*a2]`, lower values are more common than higher values:

[image]

Here is the distribution of `a2` values (by definition this is the same as the distribution of the `a3` values). The shape of the distribution is similar to the one of `a1`, but the maximum value is 0.5:

[image]

Comment: You have assumed pdf of `a2` to be proportional to the length of the line segment containing all possible values for `a1` and `a4` i.e `(1-2a_2)sqrt(2)`. Is that correct ? As the length of the line segment increases  the value of a_2 should decrease.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to think about using the Dirichlet distribution,

Well, to me it looks like Dirichlet distribution.

> but it gives no mechanism to force two of the variates to be equal.

but you don't have to. You actually have three variates from Dirichlet distribution - A, B, C, all >= 0, uniformly distributed U(0,1) so that A+B+C=1

After sampling (A, B, C) you just assign

```
a1 = A;
a2 = B/2.0;
a3 = B/2.0;
a4 = C;
```

Please take a look at how to sample thing (well, in Python)

[Generating N uniform random numbers that sum to M](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30658932/generating-n-uniform-random-numbers-that-sum-to-m/)

Comment: Thanks @SeverinPappadeux. It is a good observation. I have a doubt though which I asked you in StackExchange as it was not a code related question.

Comment: Could you edit your answer to argue why this evenly samples the space `{(a1, a2, a3, a4 | a2=a3, a1+a2+a3+a4=1, a1>0, a2>0, a3>0, a4>0}`? I've computed random variates from my answer and from yours and they have different distributions (e.g. the correlations between pairs of variables differ).

Comment: @josilber `I've computed random variates from my answer and from yours and they have different distributions`. They might be. I believe we have a case of n=3 Dirichlet distribution. Dirichlet distribution has properties of x_i within[0...1] and Sum(x_i)=1, but also parametrised by \alpha_i. Simplest case, which is sampled in my python code is where all \alpha_i=1. I'm too lazy to check, but I wouldn't be surprised  if you build Dirichlet distribution with different \alpha_i (\alpha_i = 0.5?). In such case your solution is a satisfactory answer (as well as mine)

Comment: `I believe we have a case of n=3 Dirichlet distribution.` Could you say why you believe that? I don't know if the set is a Dirichlet distribution (it's not obvious to me why it would be), but I'm pretty sure it is not a Dirichlet distribution with alpha_i=1 for all variables as you have currently suggested in your answer. Could you provide some mathematical reasoning for why you think it is Dirichlet distributed?