# Sample uniformly at random from a simplex in Python

Tags: python, random, simplex

I want to uniformly sample from a simplex in python. I found the following in R but nothing so far in python

```
 runif_in_simplex(n, simplex)
```

EDIT: Is the following solution correct?

1. generate N random numbers (N = no of vertices of simplex)
2. Normalize these N numbers (divide by sum)
3. Form the linear combination of N numbers and Vertice's coordinates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating N uniform random numbers that sum to M](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30658932/generating-n-uniform-random-numbers-that-sum-to-m)

Comment: `Is the following solution correct?` Assuming that your random numbers are floats in [0...1) range, your solution is incorrect

Answer (score 3):

Unit exponential variables is what you need (related [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32618/uniform-distribution-on-a-simplex-via-i-i-d-random-variables)).

```
def runif_in_simplex(n):
  ''' Return uniformly random vector in the n-simplex '''

  k = np.random.exponential(scale=1.0, size=n)
  return k / sum(k)
```

The procedure that you proposed is not uniformly distributed in the simplex.

### Refs

Onn, S., & Weissman, I. (2011). Generating uniform random vectors over a simplex with implications to the volume of a certain polytope and to multivariate extremes. Annals of Operations Research, 189(1), 331-342.

Comment: How do you guarantee unicity of the simplex elements?

Comment: what do you mean by unicity?

Comment: I mean that the decomposition into a simplex is unique for the vertices.

Comment: The proposed solution is to generate a uniformly random sample from the "standard simplex". But it works for every simplex by simply scaling the sides