# Make random integers (with limits) add a sum without using solver? Excel

Tags: excel, matlab, random, numbers

I am trying to choose a random integer between 0 & 6. Then, repeat that process 7 times and get the random integers to add up to exactly 40.

If possible, I would like to do this in Excel w/o Macros or in MATLAB.

What should I fill in for the question marks here?:

[image]

Comment: To clarify: are you trying to get random *integers* or random *floating point* numbers?

Comment: For it to add up to 40 it must average 40/7 which is 5.714.  That means that any 0 would make it impossible to add to 40.

Comment: How can they be random numbers from 0 to 6 if 6*7 = 42? This means that even a 3 would make it impossible to reach 42 in 7 numbers! i.e. 6*6 + 3 = 39 :/

Comment: @UJIN It makes perfect sense to randomly choose a vector from a set of vectors which is defined by a constraint. Uniform-independent is not the only meaning of "random"

Comment: @JohnColeman I agree that it make perfect sense to randomly choose something under some constraints. I was just commenting on how strict these constraints are, because, supposing he's asking for integers and not taking into consideration the ordering, there are only two vectors satisfying that condition: 4,6,6,6,6,6,6 and 5,5,6,6,6,6,6! But yes, you are right

Comment: @UJIN you are quite right that the problem as stated is too heavily constrained to be interesting if the intention is to have random integers. Presumably things like `40` are just parameters and the question of how to e.g. pick 20 random integers in the range 1 to 10 so that they sum to 100 is both interesting and somewhat hard.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600348/how-do-i-generate-random-numbers-in-an-array-that-add-up-to-a-defined-total/18600737#18600737

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker the extra constraint on the range of the numbers makes this question significantly different from (albeit related to) that question. The additional constraint makes it a more difficult problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following method iteratively calculates the allowed boundaries of the random number so that it is possible to reach the requested sum.

```
N = 7; % number of random integers to generate
total = 40; % requested sum
from = zeros(N, 1); % minimum values
to = 6*ones(N, 1); % maximum values


value = zeros(N, 1); % allocate space for solution
currentTotal = 0; % sum up to loop iteration i
for i=1:N
    minTotal = currentTotal + to(i) + sum(from(i+1:N)); % minimal sum we can achieve if the current random number equals the maximum value
    maxTotal = currentTotal + from(i) + sum(to(i+1:N)); % maximal sum we can achieve if the current random number equals the minimum value
    if minTotal > total
      to(i) = to(i) - (minTotal - total); % update to maximal allowed value
    end
    if  maxTotal < total % update the minimal allowed value
      from(i) = from(i) + (total - maxTotal);
    end
    value(i) = randi([from(i) to(i)]); % calculate the random value
    currentTotal = currentTotal + value(i); % calculate the updated sum
end

sum(value) == total
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to change the values to integers and not include the decimals?

Comment: I changed my answer to use an integer random generator. I also adapted your question to indicate you are interested in integers and not floating point numbers.